I would like to know more about the “three commonly used tile sets” mentioned in the video
Around 35 seconds into this video, three commonly used tilesets are mentioned: "15-piece, 47-piece, Reduced."

The video points out some issues with these tilesets, but it doesn't seem to explain what they are in detail.
I tried searching for terms like "15-piece tilesets game" but couldn't find relevant information.
Is it just a matter of having tiles for edges, centers, etc., to naturally end up with 15 or 47 pieces? The Dual-grid system explained in the video seems promising, but I'd like to understand the common methods first.
Can anyone provide a concrete explanation of these tilesets?
(If these terms aren't commonly used, are there general concepts like preparing edges or connection parts that are standard?)

Does this answer your question? Combinations for tiling two textures together. The "15-piece" from the video corresponds to the "Marching Squares/Corner Tiles" type described in the answer there (in turn based on prior taxonomies by Boris the Brave and Sean Howard). The "47-piece" corresponds to "The Blob" (actually 48 tiles if you have a full-foreground and a full-background tile included), and the "Reduced" corresponds to the "Rug".

Re: using the dual grid, you might also be interested in Oskar Stålberg's work (Bad North, Townscaper) which emphasizes this approach. See his Sweden Game Arena talk here for more.

It is what I wanted to know

I've closed this thread as a duplicate of the one I linked, then. If you need something that's not covered there, please feel free to edit this question and it can be re-opened, or post a new question.
